# How to get details of user who modified a parameter in aws parameter store via sns using amazon eventbridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge, aws-parameter-store

I am using the below custom pattern in aws event-bridge to get email via SNS but I also need the details of the user who modified the parameter in parameter store.

```
{
    "source": [
        "aws.ssm"
    ],
    "detail-type": [
        "Parameter Store Change"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "name": [
            "****"
        ],
        "operation": [
            "Create",
            "Update",
            "Delete",
            "LabelParameterVersion"
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to get following detail in email.
[Required detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oks5B.png)

Comment: You haven't explained what is the actual issue? The EB event does not work?

Comment: I am not able to get the user details in the mail who has modified the parameter store which has been triggered by SNS using EB.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to receive the user ARN from the event sent to the SNS topic. The sample payloads on this page indicate that the information being sent is limited. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-cwe.html